# Chrome://inspect shows my device but I can't inspect it

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-chrome, appium, inspect

I want to get my hands dirty with app automation so I've been playing around with learning Appium (if anybody has any good tutorials send em my way!). I have an app on my local machine that I'm wanting to use for testing purposes.

The app is one I've created with c# and Xamarin Forms so I have all the files and the .apk locally.

I found a video that said you could use the **chrome://inspect** page to view apps in an emulator and even inspect them. When my app is running (starting it via Visual Studio) I can see it pop up in the device list but I don't have the option to inspect it.

I'm not sure how people feel about pictures but I don't really have any code to post so I'll just show you that the app is, indeed, running and what I see on the chrome devices page.

Here is my app running
[image]

And here is the device list from chrome. You can see the emulator there but I can't do anything with it
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Usually, this happens because there are no inspectable webviews in the application. Chrome inspect view can be used only if there is a webview in the active application screen. Can you validate that if this screen is a web view?

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. I do not have a webview around anything. Guess I'll have to look that up as I'm not even familiar with what it is :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Chrome://Inspect` is a part of **Chrome Dev Tools** that lets you see port forwarded web views from the mobile in a desktop browser. This is because we cannot inspect elements in Chrome mobile (something we do in desktop browser with `CTRL+SHIFT+I`) and we have to forward the chrome mobile window to chrome desktop.

To inspect element, if you're working on a web page or web application, just simply right click on that page and choose `Inspect`

And in your case, for inspecting Android application (apk), you should use UiAutomatorViewer, AppiumStudio, Katalon mobile spy, etc...
Here is my answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58204262/7302505